# Laravel testing - Only one test is being executed when running command "php artisan test"

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, laravel-8

I'm new to testing in Laravel with PHPUnit. So please be patient with me.
I'm sure it is a beginner issue, but actually I cannot find the reason.

I've created my first unit test with Laravel. This test is running without issues and gives me a valid result.

This is my first created test (`WoodWoodConnectionTest.php`):

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Unit\Verification\Module\HCW;

use Tests\TestCase;

class WoodWoodConnectionTest extends TestCase {
    public function testVerifyWoodWoodCalculationFormulasBasedOnValuesOfExampleReport() {
        //Arrange
        $verificationDataOfHCW = new \App\Models\Nachweis\Daten\HCW();
        $verificationDataOfHCW->connection_type = \Config::get('constants.verbindungstyp.holzholz');
        $verificationDataOfHCW->service_class = \Config::get('constants.nutzungsklasse.nkl1');
        ...
        $calculationRepository = \App::make('\App\Repositories\Nachweis\HCWRepositoryImpl');

        //Act
        $calculationRepository->calculate($verificationDataOfHCW);

        //Assert
        $this->assertEquals(28.80, $verificationDataOfHCW->f_v_0_rk);
        $this->assertEquals(1.3, $verificationDataOfHCW->y_m);
        ...
    }
}
```

So I copied the test (and renamed the class, the file and the method) and modified it (`WoodConcreteConnectionTest.php`).

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Unit\Verification\Module\HCW;

use Tests\TestCase;

class WoodConcreteConnectionTest extends TestCase {
    public function testVerifyWoodConcreteCalculationFormulasBasedOnValuesOfExampleReport() {
        //Arrange
        $verificationDataOfHCW = new \App\Models\Nachweis\Daten\HCW();
        $calculationRepository = \App::make('\App\Repositories\Nachweis\HCWRepositoryImpl');

        //Act
        $calculationRepository->berechnen($verificationDataOfHCW);

        //Assert
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

But when I run

`php artisan test`

it runs only the last created test (my copy `WoodConcreteConnectionTest.php`). The first one is not being executed anymore.

[image]

Same situation, when I create a new test with

`php artisan make:test TestTest --unit`

...it only runs this test.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I noticed when I change the `TestCase` to PHPUnit's `TestCase` instead of Laravel's `TestCase`, two tests are executed (`WoodConcreteConnectionTest` and `TestTest`).

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
//use Tests\TestCase;
```

...but then I cannot use my config settings or commands like this:

```
\App::make('\App\Repositories\Nachweis\HCWRepositoryImpl');
```

My Laravel `TestCase` class looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
}
```

...and the `CreatesApplication` trait looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;

trait CreatesApplication
{
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

This is my `phpunit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Are there any other locations in a Laravel project which controls the testing?

Comment: When you switch from Laravel's `TestCase` to PHPUnit `TestCase`, that is because Laravel's `TestCase` is initializing itself, but PHPUnit is not initializing Laravel... could you show us your `testsuites` on `phpunit.xml`?

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's the reason, why I'm using Laravel's `TestCase` class, because I need to have some Laravel functionality. I have nothing configured in the `phpunit.xml`. I have added it to my original post. Please have a look

Comment: If you run `./vendor/bin/phpunit`, does it do the same?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but it actually did not solve the issue. First time I ran the command it said: `PHPUnit 9.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Warning:       Your XML configuration validates against a deprecated schema.
Suggestion:    Migrate your XML configuration using "--migrate-configuration"!

.`, then I ran the migration. After the migration the result of the command was just `PHPUnit 9.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.`.

Comment: Only that and no more output? not even a success or failure? Was it stuck in an infinite loop and you terminated it or it finished with exactly that?

Comment: To be honest, you have `filter` in your `xml`, but if you have a look at the [`Laravel's 8.x phpunit.xml on github`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/926c48e8562e36811159d615ba27ebb2929d0378/phpunit.xml#L15-L19) you will see it is using `coverage`, could you replace `filter` with that please?

Comment: What are the names and directories where these files are located? Have you confirmed that the path matches the namespace, and the file name matches the class name, *including upper and lower case*?

Comment: @matiaslauriti: I've copied the complete `phpunit.xml` from Laravel source. Result is the same. Only one test is being executed. No more output with running `./vendor/bin/phpunit`. @miken32: Yes, the path is being exactly as the namespace including upper and lowercase.

Comment: I have now also updated all packages again. But also no effect on the result.

Comment: Are you able to create and run 2 simple tests in a completely new project - it would be good to eliminate any environment configuration issues and eliminate all possible causes except something inside this particular project.

Comment: Additionally, are you able to run both tests indipendently using: `php artisan test --filter SomeTest`

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius yeah, running the Tests indipendently works, but of course it would be fine to run them all by one command. I will try to do the trial in a new project. Maybe I need to say this project was built in laravel 5.4 a long time ago and been upgraded to the current version step by step. Maybe this could be a reason for this strange behaviour, too. Therefore I asked, which parts in a laravel solution control the testing.